# Point separating function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I'm trying to prove that the set  $P = \{p: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to R \; \mid \; \text{p is a polynomial}\}$ is dense in $C( [0,1] \times [0,1], R)$. I'm stuck trying to find a points separating function. (obviously using the Stone Wierestrass approx).

Here is what I got so far: I thing the function that is the graph of $x$ and $\sin(x)$ should be points separating right?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I misunderstood your notation initially.

$x \mapsto \sin(x)$ isn't a polynomial function, so we'll have to try something else.

Here's something. Pick a point $(x_0,y_0) \in [0,1]^2$. Then the square of the distance between $(x_0,y_0)$ and another point $(x,y)$ is a familiar polynomial in $x$ and $y$, and is only $0$ if $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0)$.

Note that this is actually way more than we need; this function works for our initial point $(x_0,y_0)$ and any other point.

Comment: Wouldn't I need a polynomial (x,y) that maps every unique (x, y) to a unique z? otherwise I would have just used f(x)=x

Comment: Ah, I think I misread your notation. You're talking about maps from a *square* $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ into $\mathbb R$?

Comment: My bad, I typed it wrong. Edited.

Comment: Right, and that would always work because, we don't have any points in the "negative quadrants" Ah! Thanks

Comment: Sure. You can click the little check mark to accept this answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here would be to take 2 different functions: f(x,y) = x and g(x, y)= y
That works because it need not be one function that separates all points.